# Print SVG edge to edge from webpage

Tags: javascript, css, svg, printing

I've carefully crafted an svg generator for printing labels.
It is very important that the dimensions are correct if the labels are not to look weird.
[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/617874/Labels/Label%202x5%20web.svg) is an example of a generated label sheet.

When printing from the web, the browser adds a lot of margins. The above example is supposed to have margins that are top: 7mm, right/left: 4.2mm bottom: 5mm.

When printing it is a lot more. If I copy paste the svg into a vector graphics app it prints perfectly!

Is there any way, programmatically from JavaScript or by CSS to tell the browser to NOT do header/footer and to not add any margins of its own?

Comment: You might want to look into css's [`@media types`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html#at-media-rule), specifically `@media print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory this is the correct way:

```
@page {
    margin: 7mm 4.2mm 5mm;
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

But styling for printing is too painful among all browsers (doesn't work consistently)

Comment: I'll try fiddeling with it. Have an upvote for now, if it works I'll give the check mark.

Comment: Since margins are specd in the svg I used "margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm"
But it works great in the version of chrome I'm using which is good enough for me!